# Git: How to get another remote branch in a local repository cloned with --single-branch?

Tags: git

I have a repository that I cloned with the `--single-branch` option. Now someone else created a new branch that I need to pull for my particular work on this repository.

I know that the single branch option adds a line like

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

to the git configuration with a specific branch name instead of a `*` and I could simply add another line like this to config. But there is also a way to achieve this through a single git command - I used it in the past, I just absolutely don't remember which command does this. Would be great if someone could jog my memory.

Comment: Where are you pulling this branch? If you don't want to merge it, then why not fetch it instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox There is a new branch on the remote I cloned from and I want to have this in my local repository/working copy, so I can switch to it and add apply my changes to it. But because it is configured to just consider `master` (in this example), git doesn't show me the other branches that are present on the remote. I need to add the refspec for the new branch first. The question is: How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I found the command I tried to remember: To add another branch to fetch without having to specify refspecs manually one can use the `set-branches` sub-command of `git remote`:

```
$ git remote set-branches --add <remote> <branch>
```

This adds the proper refspec to the remote's configuration. The `--add` option is quite important here because without it the new branch would replace the currently configured ones.

Answer (score 2):

The line is to configure a refspec. You can specify it in the command.

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo
```

Comment: And you can add it to the defaults, `git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo`

Comment: I know about the refspecs and that I can add it by editing the config file directly or with this command. I was looking for the way without specifying a refspec (sorry if I wasn't clear enough about this). In the meantime I found the answer (again) and added it, so it might help others as well.